# File handling in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I wanted to write a cobol program to read a file EMP-GRADE with 4 fields(EMPID,NAME,STREAM,GRADE) and display the details of employees who have scored a grade 'A' in the output. I used on-line Cobol compiler.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE1.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. 
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT EMPFILE ASSIGN TO 'input.txt'
ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL 
ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS.
SELECT EMPA ASSIGN TO 'util.cobc'
ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL 
ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL. 
DATA DIVISION. 
FILE SECTION. 
FD EMPFILE. 
01 NEWFILE. 
05 FS-EMPID PIC 9(6). 
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-NAME PIC A(10).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-STREAM PIC A(10).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-GRADE PIC A(1).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
FD EMPA.
01 OUTFILE.
05 FS-EMPID-OUT PIC 9(6). 
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-NAME-OUT PIC A(10).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-STREAM-OUT PIC A(10).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
05 FS-GRADE-OUT PIC A(1).
05 FILLER PIC X(50).
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
01 WS-EOF PIC A(1) VALUE "N". 
01 WS-FILE-STATUS PIC X(2). 
PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
MAIN-PARA. 
OPEN INPUT EMPFILE 
OPEN OUTPUT EMPA
PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT
Perform Until WS-EOF = "Y"
    IF FS-GRADE='A'
        MOVE NEWFILE TO OUTFILE
        WRITE OUTFILE
        END-WRITE
        DISPLAY OUTFILE
    ELSE
    DISPLAY 'NO A GRADE STUDENT IN THE LIST'
    END-IF
    PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT 
    END-PERFORM
CLOSE EMPFILE.
CLOSE EMPA.
STOP RUN. 
MAIN-PARA-EXIT. 
EXIT. 
READ-PARA. 
READ EMPFILE
AT END MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF 
NOT AT END DISPLAY NEWFILE 
END-READ. 
READ-PARA-EXIT.
EXIT.
```

The above is my  Updated code and then I gave input in the 'input.txt' and I got output as follows

```
11111   AISHU   JAVA    B
22222   RANJU   MAINF   A
```

NO A GRADE STUDENT IN THE LIST'

Comment: Why don't you download GnuCOBOL from SorceForge. I don't think you can write a file withe any of the online compile sites (but I could be wrong). It is *impossible8 that you got the output correctly, because you only have one WRITE which happens after the end of the input file, and is only executed if the last record is still available (depends on compiler) and only if it is an A.

Comment: Instead of DISPLAYing the entire record, why don't you DISPLAY the fields you are interested in, only, which is an easy way (sometimes people like to compile/link/re-run to save the effort of counting) to see if your test data matches your field definitions. From the sample you've shown, that's a big, flat, NO.

Comment: @BillWoodger As You suggested, I downloaded offline COBOL Compiler and I compiled my code but I got some doubt in that, In offline compiler how  should  I add input file and output file?

Comment: That's a new question, and not so good for the Q^A format of SO. If you back to the SourceForge for GnuCOBOL you'll find a discussion area where even the most basic questions can be discussed (rather than just answered). Also look for Gary Cutler's manual, https://www.linkedin.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fopencobol%2Eadd1tocobol%2Ecom%2FGNUCobol2%2Epdf&urlhash=zBo6&_t=tracking_anet - there's more than one way to do what you want, but if you have a look at the SELECT it should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
MAIN-PARA. 
    OPEN INPUT EMPFILE 
    OPEN OUTPUT EMPA
    PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT UNTIL WS-EOF = ‘Y’
    CLOSE EMPFILE.
    CLOSE EMPA.
    STOP RUN. 
MAIN-PARA-EXIT. 
    EXIT. 
READ-PARA. 
    READ EMPFILE
        AT END 
            MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF 
            IF WS-F='M' THEN
                DISPLAY 'NO A GRADE STUDENT IN THE LIST'
            END-IF
        NOT AT END DISPLAY NEWFILE
            IF FS-GRADE='A' THEN
                MOVE ‘M’ TO WS-F
                MOVE NEWFILE TO OUTFILE
                WRITE OUTFILE
                END-WRITE
                DISPLAY OUTFILE
            ELSE
                CONTINUE 
            END-IF
    END-READ. 
READ-PARA-EXIT.
    EXIT.
```

Comment: How did you get an upvote for that? It looked horrible, and it doesn't work. You need to look at using the FILE STATUS clause of the SELECT, and checking the file-status fields after each IO. The AT END/NOT AT END tangle is a mess. Using the value of the file-status field for your input file makes that easy and clear, especially when yusing 88s. Why the THRU, other than the beginner used it. It is unnecessary. Why the CONTINUE in the ELSE?  No purpose in the MAIN-PARA or its exit. Your should test it, get it to work, and try to improve on it, it'll improve your COBOL coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading your entire input file with the

```
PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT UNTIL WS-EOF="Y"
```

statement.  You must instead read a record, process it, read the next record, process it, and so forth.

```
OPEN INPUT EMPFILE  
OPEN OUTPUT EMPA 
PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT

Perform Until WS-EOF = "Y"
    IF FS-GRADE='A'
        MOVE NEWFILE TO OUTFILE
        WRITE OUTFILE
        DISPLAY OUTFILE
    END-IF
    PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT 
End-Perform

CLOSE EMPFILE 
CLOSE EMPA 
STOP RUN.
```

There are probably any number of other improvements to be made based on the actual requirements for the exercise, but I think this solves your immediate problem.

Note the two separate `PERFORMs` of `READ-PARA`.  The first is sometimes called a *priming read*, which is a helpful technique to learn.